# Following MVVM pattern, how to create a "Settings" function that sets the data-bound item values in other user controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

**!!Please see the second edit at the bottom first!**

A simplified version of my problem: I have two simple user controls Apple and Banana (view) with their corresponding view models containing 2 properties each. I also have a ListBox as the "Settings" of Apple and Banana properties.

Apple:

```
<UserControl>  
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">  
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,20,0" Text="{Binding AppleID}"/>  
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Size}"/>  
    </StackPanel>  
</UserControl>
```

Banana:

```
<UserControl>  
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,20,0"  Text="{Binding BananaID}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Length}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Apple VM:

```
public class AppleViewModel : Notifier
{
    private string appleID;
    public string AppleID
    {
        get => appleID; set
        {
            appleID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AppleID");
        }
    }
    private int size;
    public int Size
    {
        get => size; set
        {
            size = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Size");
        }
    }
}
```

Banana VM:

```
public class BananaViewModel : Notifier
{
    private string bananaID;
    public string BananaID
    {
        get => bananaID; set
        {
            bananaID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BananaID");
        }
    }
    private int length;
    public int Length
    {
        get => length; set
        {
            length = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Length");
        }
    }
}
```

The mainwindow looks like this:

```
<Window>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <local:AppleControlxaml x:Name="apple"/>
        <local:BananaControl x:Name="banana"/>
        <ListBox>

        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

For quicker setup I assigned the DataContext in code behind in mainwindow. In the real situation I used window viewmodel instead.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        apple.DataContext = new AppleViewModel()
        {
            AppleID = "Apple001",
            Size = 10,
        };
        banana.DataContext = new BananaViewModel()
        {
            BananaID = "Banana002",
            Length = 10
        };
    }
}
```

And now I wish the listBox control displays and allows user to set the property values of the user control being focused. A typical interaction would be Select/Mousedown Apple user control area -> Change length in listbox -> See that apple user control values changed.

And if the user select/mousedown Banana user control, he/she should be able to do the same.

The question is: How can I implement this settings functionality using MVVM and databinding? I tried creating a ObservableCollection for the viewbox's ItemsSource to bind to, but how can makes sure the collection updates the apple view model correctly?

Sorry for the long post. I'm rather new to stackoverflow.

---

**Second edit**

My apologies, but my description might have made the problem more confusing. The properties should use ItemsControl instead of a ListBox. Here is the desired behavior.
[The UI when apple user control is MouseDown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoMTe.png) [The UI when banana user control is MouseDown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIbe6.png)

When values in Properties are changed by the user, the user control (apple or banana) should update their values as well.

I suspect that I should data-bind the ItemsSource property in Properties's ItemControl to the actual properties of AppleVM and BananaVM, but I am not sure how I can do that properly using data-binding.

Here's the updated MainWindow.xaml. Other codes are mostly unchanged from the first edit

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <local:AppleControl x:Name="apple1" MouseDown="apple1_MouseDown"/>
            <local:BananaControl x:Name="banana1" MouseDown="banana1_MouseDown"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Properties of selected item" Foreground="Blue" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
            <ItemsControl Name="properties" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyValue}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you my idea according to what I understood from your question.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private AppleViewModel appleViewModel;
    public AppleViewModel AppleViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.appleViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.appleViewModel != value)
            {
                this.appleViewModel = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private BananaViewModel bananaViewModel;
    public BananaViewModel BananaViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bananaViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.bananaViewModel != value)
            {
                this.bananaViewModel = value;
            }
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.AppleViewModel = new AppleViewModel();
        this.AppleViewModel.AppleID = "Apple001";
        this.AppleViewModel.Size = 10;

        this.BananaViewModel = new BananaViewModel();
        this.BananaViewModel.BananaID = "Banana001";
        this.BananaViewModel.Length = 10;

        apple.DataContext = this.AppleViewModel;

        banana.DataContext = this.BananaViewModel;

        ObservableCollection<int> sizes = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            sizes.Add(i);
        }

        ListBox.ItemsSource = sizes;

    }

    private void ListBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.AppleViewModel.IsSelected)
        {
            this.AppleViewModel.Size = (int)ListBox.SelectedItem;
        }
        if (this.BananaViewModel.IsSelected)
        {
            this.BananaViewModel.Length = (int)ListBox.SelectedItem;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <wpfApplication4:AppleControlxaml x:Name="apple"/>
        <wpfApplication4:BananaControl x:Name="banana"/>
        <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_OnSelectionChanged" x:Name="ListBox">
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Your fruit VMs should have a new property called IsSelected like:

```
private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isSelected;

        }
        set
        {
            this.isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
```

And your fruits control should have this too

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
```

If you don't want to use this checkbox control just tell me and i will try to find a more accurate answer

---

Edit for clarify your edit (xD):

Let's say you have already created your "SettingsVM" with its Value and its Description properties. Now you want to show your selected fruit settings on your ListBox. So let's go...
Everytime your fruit changes, your SettingsVM's properties has to change too in order to show the right fruit. In your "banana1_MouseDown" or "apple1_MouseDown" you have to initialize your SettingsVM with their properties so you can create a method to do it.

```
private void InitializeSettingsVM(int value, string description)
    {
      //Same like you do when you initialize your Banana/AppleVM in your MainWindow initialize.
      this.SettingsVM.Value = value;
      this.SettingsVM.Description = description;
    }
```

In your banana1_MouseDown/apple1_MouseDown you should do:

```
private void banana1_MouseDown(whateveryouhavehere)
   {
     //Whatever you do here
     this.InitializeSettingsVM(this.BananaViewModel.Length,this.BananaViewModel.BananaID);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! However is it possible for the ItemsSource of the listbox to be directly data bound to the appleVM or bananaVM properties instead of a collection of ints? Please also check my 2nd edit for the desired behavior.

Comment: In your banana1_MouseDown and your apple1_MouseDown you could change your "properties" itemcontrol itemsource. Because they are different VM you should create another VM to bind it to the itemsControl let say "ItemsControlVM" which will have a description and a value(?) then when you change your selection you initialize your ItemsControlVM with your desired values. I hope I explained myself... if I didn't just tell me and i will post a new answer with code.

Comment: Does that mean I have to manually make sure that the appleVM, bananaVM, and the new "propertiesVM" are in synch in the code when some of the values changes? Say user make changes in "Properties" for the apple and both propertiesVM and appleVM has to change in the back?

Comment: That’s it. You have a listbox which has an itemsource set with a VM so everytime your fruit changes you have to update your settingsVM. You can create a private method like private void InitializeSettingsVM(int size, string description) and when you select the fruit you call that method and set your settingsVM properties. Doing this you are “closer” to SOLID and it will be easier to read. That’s the way it should be done. I’ll update my answer asap so you can see it.

Comment: Check the edit and if it helps you/answers your question please check it as correct answer/upvote

Comment: Awesome! This is what I am looking for. Thank you very much for spending so much time teaching a newbie Juan! I will look into SOLID as well.

Comment: I’m so glad I helped you. This is far from SOLID but it’s a start.